# sed problem with scripting

Tags: scripts, sed

I am trying to run a script using sed 
i runing like this

```
for et in   1 # 2 3
    do

      if [ -d ET$et ]; then rm -rf ET$et; fi

        mkdir ET$et
        cd ET$et
        cp  $home/step_$i/FDE/diabatA/run.adf .
        cp  $home/step_$i/FDE/diabatA/mas$i.xyz .

        awk1=`awk '/type=fde/{print NR }' run.adf | head -1`
        awk2=`$(echo "$a+379" | bc -l )`
       sed -n "$awk1,"$awk2"p" run.adf > first

        awk3=`awk '/ATOMS/{print NR +1}' first`
        awk4=`cat mas$i.xyz | wc -l`
        awk4=$( echo "$awk4-1" | bc -l )
        awk5=`awk "/ATOMS/{print NR +"${awk4}" }" run.adf`
        sed -n "$awk3,"$awk4"p" first > atoms

        par=$( echo "$awk4-99" | bc -l )
        rho1=$(cat atoms | head -34 )
        rho2=$(cat atoms | head -64 | tail -31)
        rho3=$(cat atoms | head -97 | tail -33)
        rhoall=$(cat atoms | tail -${par} )

        echo -e "$rho1\n$rho2\n$rhoall" > eje
done
```

but is telling me this:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unexpected `,'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
```

Please, I appreciate any help with this issue...

Thanks 
Pablo

Answer (score 1):

Both your `sed` expressions look malformed... here's the first:

```
sed -n "$awk1,"$awk2"p" run.adf > first
```

I would suggest you're actually looking for:

```
sed -n "s/$awk1/$awk2/p" run.adf > first
```

And alter the second one similarly.

```
sed -n "s/$awk3/$awk4/p" first > atoms
```

Comment: Thanks, However is telling me :
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `2'
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. See the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

The `unknown command ','` means that either `$awk1` or `$awk3` is empty. Instead of a line number, the first thing sed sees is a comma.

You need to do something if "run.adf" does *not* contain /type=fde/ or /ATOMS/

I highly recommend using better variable names: "awk1" does not convey to the reader that it contains a line number.

Your quoting could be more readable: `sed -n "${awk1},${awk2}p"`